# Primefaces datatable row not complete rendered after rowedit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm new with jsf and Primefaces and have a curious issue with datatable:
I use the row Edit function. Everything works well, including saving the changed values to database. But after ending of edit mode, the last two fields of the edited row are not shown (no border and no value, it seems that these fields are just not rendered). The fields above and below the edited row are shown properly.

Here is the code. Please help, I'm desperate..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<ui:composition template="../common/BaseTemplate.xhtml" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <ui:define name="pageTitle">Meilensteine</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
    <f:event listener="#{meilensteineController.init}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:subview id="pnlMeilensteine" binding="#{root}">
    <div class="MainZoom">


            <p:dataTable id="tblMeilensteine" binding="#{table}" widgetVar="MeilensteineSearchTable"
                var="item" value="#{meilensteineController.list}" editable="true"
                filteredValue="#{meilensteineController.filteredValue}"
                scrollable="true" liveScroll="false" 
                scrollHeight="#{screen.screenHeight}" scrollWidth="#{screen.screenWidth}"
                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.id}" scrollRows="100">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{meilensteineController.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" update=":form:messages" />
<p:column style="min-width: 35px; width: 35px; ">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

                <p:column rendered="false" sortBy="#{item.id}" filterBy="#{item.id}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Id">

                            <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
                        </p:column>

                <p:column rendered="false" sortBy="#{item.projekt}" filterBy="#{item.projekt}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Projekt">

                    <h:outputText value="#{item.projekt}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 300px; width: 300px; " sortBy="#{item.bezeichnung}" filterBy="#{item.bezeichnung}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Bezeichnung">

                    <p:cellEditor >
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.bezeichnung}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText readonly ="#{item.posInfoscreen > 0}" style="width:300px" value="#{item.bezeichnung}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 75px; width: 75px;" sortBy="#{item.datumSoll}" filterBy="#{item.datumSoll}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Datumsoll">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText style="color: #{meilensteineController.getBgcolor(item.datumSoll,item.erledigt)}" value="#{item.datumSoll}">
                                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:calendar readonlyInput="true" navigator="true"
                                value="#{item.datumSoll}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                                label="Datum Soll" styleClass="normalDate"></p:calendar>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>


                <p:column style="min-width: 75px; width: 75px; " sortBy="#{item.poenalisiert}" filterBy="#{item.poenalisiert}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Pönalisiert">

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true"
                                value="#{item.poenalisiert}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="false"
                                value="#{item.poenalisiert}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 75px; width: 75px; " sortBy="#{item.erledigt}" filterBy="#{item.erledigt}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Erledigt">

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" value="#{item.erledigt}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="false"
                                value="#{item.erledigt}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 75px; width: 75px; " sortBy="#{item.datumIst}" filterBy="#{item.datumIst}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Datumist">

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.datumIst}">
                                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:calendar readonlyInput="true" navigator="true"
                                value="#{item.datumIst}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" label="Datum Ist"
                                styleClass="normalDate"></p:calendar>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 200px; width: 200px; " sortBy="#{item.bemerkung}" filterBy="#{item.bemerkung}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Bemerkung">

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.bemerkung}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText style="width:200px" value="#{item.bemerkung}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 150px; width: 150px; " sortBy="#{item.user}" filterBy="#{item.user}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="User">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.user}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 150px; width: 150px; " sortBy="#{item.link}" filterBy="#{item.link}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Link">

                    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus" actionListener="#{meilensteineController.PickRowToUpload(item)}"
                         oncomplete="PF('uploadFileDialog').show();" width="20px" rendered="#{item.link eq '' or item.link eq null}"/>

                    <h:commandLink value="#{meilensteineController.retriveActualFile(item.link)}" rendered="#{not(item.link eq '' or item.link eq null)}">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{meilensteineController.downloadFile(item.link)}" />  
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" actionListener="#{meilensteineController.PickRowToUpload(item)}"
                         oncomplete="PF('confirmationDialog').show();" rendered="#{not(item.link eq '' or item.link eq null)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 85px; width: 85px; " sortBy="#{item.letzterEintrag}" filterBy="#{item.letzterEintrag}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="LetzterEintrag">

                    <h:outputText value="#{item.letzterEintrag}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="min-width: 35px; width: 35px; " sortBy="#{item.posInfoscreen}" filterBy="#{item.posInfoscreen}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Pos">


                            <h:outputText value="#{item.posInfoscreen}" />

                </p:column>
                <p:column style="min-width: 85px; width: 85px; " sortBy="#{item.doc}" filterBy="#{item.doc}"
                    filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;" headerText="Dokument">


                            <h:outputText value="#{item.doc}" />

                </p:column>
                <p:column style="min-width: 30px; width: 30px; ">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

                <p:column rendered="true" style="min-width: 30px; width: 30px; ">
                    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"
                        actionListener="#{meilensteineController.PickRowToDelete(item)}"
                        process="@this" oncomplete="PF('confirmDelDialog').show();"
                        update="#{meilensteineController.cid(deldlMeilensteine)},:form:messages" />
                </p:column>

                <f:facet name="footer" style="align:left">
                    <table class="tabFooter" style="width: 350px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tabFooter" style="width: 50px"><p:commandButton
                                    id="New" value="New" title="Creates new recordset"
                                    actionListener="#{meilensteineController.initAddnew}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('addNewDialog').show();" update=":form:messages"></p:commandButton>
                                <p:tooltip for="New" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="tabFooter" style="width: 100px">Records:
                                #{meilensteineController.count}</td>
                            <td><h:outputText value=" Search:" /> <p:inputText
                                    styleClass="tabFooter" id="globalFilter"
                                    onkeyup="PF('MeilensteineSearchTable').filter()" style="width:250px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Bitte Löschen bestätigen" widgetVar="confirmDelDialog" resizable="false"  modal="false">
                <h:panelGrid id="delMeilensteine" binding="#{deldlMeilensteine}" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <h:outputText value="Bezeichnung" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{meilensteineController.rowToDelete.bezeichnung}"  style="font-weight:bold"/>                                               
                    <p:commandButton id="del" actionListener="#{meilensteineController.Delete( meilensteineController.rowToDelete)}"   process="@this" oncomplete="PF('confirmDelDialog').hide()"  
                                     update="tblMeilensteine,:form:messages" value="#{res['GEN_Delete']}"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="cancelDel" onclick="PF('confirmDelDialog').hide()" value="#{res['GEN_Cancel']}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
            <p:dialog header="Neuer Meilenstein" widgetVar="addNewDialog" resizable="false" id="addNewDlg"  modal="false">
                <h:panelGrid id="addNew" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <h:outputText value="Bezeichnung" />    
                    <p:inputText id="Bezeichnung" value="#{meilensteineController.newRow.bezeichnung}"/>

                    <p:commandButton id="addButton" action="#{meilensteineController.addRow( meilensteineController.newRow)}"   process="addNewDlg @this" update="tblMeilensteine,:form:messages" value="#{res['GEN_Save']}"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="cancelAdd" onclick="PF('addNewDialog').hide()" value="#{res['GEN_Cancel']}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:dialog>
            </div>
        </f:subview>         

        <p:dialog width="500" header="File Upload" widgetVar="uploadFileDialog" resizable="false" modal="false" >
            <p:panel id="uploadFile" styleClass="nobord">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{meilensteineController.uploadFile}" 
                                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" oncomplete="PF('uploadFileDialog').hide()"
                                update="messages2,form:pnlMeilensteine:tblMeilensteine" sizeLimit="50000000" multiple = "false" >
                            </p:fileUpload>  

                            <p:growl id="messages2" showDetail="true"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:confirmDialog  message="#{res['MIL_ConfirmMessage']}" header="Confirmation" widgetVar="confirmationDialog" resizable="false" modal="false" >
            <p:commandButton value="#{res['MIL_Yes']}"  oncomplete="PF('confirmationDialog').hide()"
                update="messages3,form:pnlMeilensteine:tblMeilensteine" action="#{meilensteineController.deleteFile}" />

            <p:commandButton value="#{res['MIL_No']}" onclick="PF('confirmationDialog').hide()" type="button" />
            <p:growl id="messages3" showDetail="true"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: The last column is rendered conditionally, are you sure `item.doc` is not `null` ? And the one before the last one is always empty according to your code. What did you expect ? Beside that, what is `deldlMeilensteine` ? I don't understand, so will the JSF container..

Comment: forget the special conditions, the behaviour ocurs also without any conditions in the column. The column before the last column is the rowEditor-Column (it's not empty, it has just no header). It happens always with the last two columns, indepent of the content.

Comment: Might be related to the object `item.doc`..what's its type/class ? Then also what's `deldlMeilensteine` ? If it's a String , you should use `''`.

Comment: I've posted the complete code for better understanding. item.doc is a database-field. When this field is not null, the entry shall allowed to delete

Comment: I found the solution after 5 hours of trial: The datatable doesn't like the columns marked as rendered="false".Removing this columns completly solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, it's good that you found the solution by yourself. Maybe you can post the answer and accept it.